# ldapdelete and ldapsearch on linux platform

Tags: ldap

i am new to stackoverflow and Ldap if am asking stupid / easy pls do not mind.
am using linux platform i need command for below two thing
1) list all the users of a LDAP group name called Group1 
i used filter with (objectclass=*) it showing all the information but i need to have only users name of group1.

And the other one

2) It has to delete all the users one by one or all together at once of group name called group1.

Platform : linux

i used ldapdelete but not succussed

Here is the query I'm trying to use, and its result:

```
ldapdelete -h myhost.com -p 389 -v "CN=sharma\,varma,CN=GAS_TEST2,OU=Delegated,OU=Groups,DC=gar,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com" ldap_initialize( ldap://myhost.com:389 ) 
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started SASL username: lab_bldmstr@myhost.COM SASL SSF: 56 SASL installing layers deleting entry "CN=sharma\,varma,CN=GAS_TEST2,OU=Delegated,OU=Groups,DC=gar,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com" –

ldap_delete: No such object (32) matched DN: CN=GAS_TEST2,OU=Delegated,OU=Groups,DC=gar,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com 
additional info: 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of: 'CN=GAS_TEST2,OU=Delegated,OU=Groups,DC=gar,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com'
```

Can somebody give me a hint of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you read at least one ldap or openldap howto ? I'm afraid it seems seems you didn't bother. I recommend you to delete this question, and come back with some real problem after you do general ldap research.

Comment: i googled for how to delete from ldap / and search tried several times
it is able to show the users list and also other information by using objectclass=* 
when it comes to delete users form ldapgroup i could not

Comment: so, where is your ldap delete query which was unsuccessful? what is error message? where is source of information you tried to use? remember to obscure password when pasting detailed info, and try to ASK the question instead of "please help me on this". You might want to go to superuser.com with this anyway.

Comment: `cn=sharma\,varma` does not exist under the specified matched DN, therefore it cannot be deleted.

Comment: ldapserach output
ldapsearch -h corpad.glb.xyz.com -p 389 -v -s base -b "CN=GAS_TEST2,OU=Delegated,OU=Groups,DC=gar,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com" "member"
ldap_initialize( ldap://corpad.glb.xyz.com:389 )
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: lab_bldmstr@GAR.CORP.xyz.COM
SASL SSF: 56
SASL installing layers
filter: (objectclass=*)

Comment: requesting: member

dn: CN=GAS_TEST,OU=Delegated,OU=Groups,DC=gar,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com
member: CN=sharma\, Kumar,OU=Workers,DC=gar,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com